# Как выключить абсолютно все пункты в dropdown в Unity через код?

Tags: c#, unity3d, dropdown

Мне надо чтобы не было выбрано ни одного пункта в dropdown unity. Как это сделать?

Comment: dropdown.options.Clear(); ?

Comment: Здравствуйте. Это не то. Мне нужно выключить пункты, чтобы не один пункт не был выбран. Clear() очищает опции, а не выключает

Comment: Я так думаю, что там есть св-во по типу "SelectedItem", просто в него null установить может быть?